# Nullable enums(??) and LinqToSQL

Tags: linq-to-sql, enums, null

I have the following statement:

```
select new Action {
     ParentContentType = action.ParentContentType != null ? (ContentType)Enum.ToObject(typeof(ContentType), action.ParentContentType) : null 
};
```

ParentContentType is a nullable enum of type ContentType

action.ParentContentType maps to a database table which is a nullable int.

If action.ParentContentType **isnt** null, I determine the enum value using:

```
(ContentType)Enum.ToObject(typeof(ContentType), action.ParentContentType)
```

In the case of when action.ParentContentType **IS** null I try to set the nullable enum to the value null.

This doesnt compile and I get:

```
Error   1 Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between ContentType' and '<null>'
```

**EDIT**

I *could* create a null enum value.. ie ContentType.EMPTY.

However:

ParentContentType = action.ParentContentType == null ? ContentType.EMPTY : (ContentType)Enum.ToObject(typeof(ContentType), action.ParentContentType)
};

Doesnt work either!

I get the exception:

```
The argument 'value' was the wrong type. Expected 'Enums.ContentType'. Actual 'System.Object'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with your idea of `ContentType.Null` or `ContentType.Empty` otherwise you will be checking for nulls all throughout your application... Plus `ContentType.Empty` is more descriptive.

Answer (score 1):

Oddly:

```
ParentContentType = action.ParentContentType == null ? ContentType.EMPTY : (ContentType)Enum.ToObject(typeof(ContentType), action.ParentContentType)
```

results in an exception:

```
The argument 'value' was the wrong type. Expected 'Enums.ContentType'. Actual 'System.Object'.
```

WTF?

Comment: Well is ParentContentType an enum too? Then should it have a ContentType.Empty?

Comment: action.ParentContentType is a nullable int and is sourced from the DB

Comment: However, the value in the db should never == null. DOh!

Comment: The above compiled and ran for me as well. I don't know -- we must be missing something about the definition of the types.

Comment: I just got this issue in a code base I maintain.. Not sure what the solution is?

Answer (score 0):

`null` is untyped. You have to cast it explicitly because the ? operator in C# requires that the second argument must be of the exact same type (or implicitly convertible) as the first.

Because the two must be of the same type, and `null` cannot be cast to a value type, they both must of the nullable type:

```
select new Action {
  ParentContentType = action.ParentContentType != null ?
    (ContentType?)Enum.ToObject(typeof(ContentType), action.ParentContentType) :
    (ContentType?)null 
};
```

However, this is pretty obscure. It never even occurred to me that you could create a nullable of an enum (I guess you can, since you posted the question -- I've never tried).

You will probably be better off with an enum value that means "nothing", as you suggested. That would be less surprising to most developers. You just don't expect an `enum` to be nullable.

Comment: Actually in this case casting the null will result in an exception " Could not translate expression"!

Comment: That's weird. The above code compiled and ran for me. Can you post the definition of ParentContentType's type?